# Cannot initialize two VideoCapture instances in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, webcam-capture

I've been trying to record video using two WebCams in my Raspberry Pi for a project I'm working on.
I tried using OpenCV VideoCapture function to do this and it works just fine on my Laptop, but when I try to run my script in the Raspberry Pi it just won't load and I get this error

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1761) ha
ndleMessage Opencv | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v
412srco reported: Cannot identify device '/dev/video-1'.
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) ope
n Opencv | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) is
ipelinePlaying opencv | GStreamer warning: Gstreamer: pipeline have not been cre
ated
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) ope
n Opencv | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, d
uration=-1
```

I'm just calling a function to save a video of certain length, here it is (it's also  in this [repo](https://github.com/open-pisciculture/prueba_concepto/blob/main/working_programs/run_wfe_sv_dualcam_laptop.py)):

```
def save_video_len(video_len):
    video_frames_1 = []
    video_frames_2 = []
    cap_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Index '0' is the default one
    cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2) # Index '2' was obtained by trial and error
    fps_1 = cap_1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Getting FPS for Cam 1
    fps_2 = cap_2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Getting FPS for Cam 2
    # print(f'FPS 1: {fps_1}\nFPS 2: {fps_2}')

    frame_1 = np.array([])
    frame_2 = np.array([])
    t0 = time.time()
    t1 = t0
    date_0 = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    out_1 = cv2.VideoWriter(f'cam1_video_date_{date_0}.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), fps_1, (320,240) )
    out_2 = cv2.VideoWriter(f'cam2_video_date_{date_0}.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), fps_2, (320,240) )

    while t1 - t0 < video_len:
        date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        t1 = time.time()

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret_1, frame_1 = cap_1.read()
        ret_2, frame_2 = cap_2.read()
        # Added date to video frame
        frame_1 = cv2.putText(frame_1, date, (10,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=0.5, color=(0,255,0))
        frame_1 = cv2.resize(frame_1, (320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame_2 = cv2.putText(frame_2, date, (10,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=0.5, color=(0,255,0))
        frame_2 = cv2.resize(frame_2, (320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        out_1.write(frame_1)
        out_2.write(frame_2)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 1', frame_1)
        cv2.imshow('Cam 2', frame_2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        video_frames_1.append(frame_1)
        video_frames_2.append(frame_2)

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap_1.release()
    cap_2.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also tried using the imutils.video.VideoStream function and I get the same problem. Also, when I just leave one WebCam, it works just fine, for both cases.

If anyone knows a better approach to this issue, or if I'm doing something wrong, I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some dependencies, try to install all
The apt packages from here under step 2, https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/ .